# R Cronbach's alpha -- rbindlist error

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new to R. I'm trying to calculate Cronbach's alpha (from psych package) for a data set. The data set looks like this:

```
R> belong_data
      belong.q1 belong.q2 belong.q3 belong.q4 belong.q5
   1:        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
   2:         5         5         5         5         5
   3:        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
   4:         5         5         4         5         5
   5:         4         5         4         3         3
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
R> alpha(belong_data)
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill) : 
  Item 2 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```

I don't understand where the rbindlist call is coming from or how to feed in the correct data structure. The data set itself ("belong_data") is a data.frame. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Is it though? It looks like one, but it might not be. What does `dput(head(belong_data))` give you?

Comment: @thelatemail oh, you mean maybe belong_data is not a dataframe? Hm. 
class(belong_data) gives "[1] "data.table" "data.frame"" but typeof(belong_data) gives "[1] "list""

Comment: As to your specific question... R> dput(head(belong_data))
structure(list(belong.q1 = c(NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 4L, 5L), belong.q2 = c(NA, 
5L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L), belong.q3 = c(NA, 5L, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L), belong.q4 = c(NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 3L, 5L), belong.q5 = c(NA, 5L, NA, 5L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("belong.q1", "belong.q2", "belong.q3", "belong.q4", "belong.q5"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f862a2c2da0>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** This issue happened because `psych::alpha` creates a `matrix` and binds tries to bind that matrix to the input data.table. However `rbind` (which calls `rbindlist` internally) for data.table only handled `list / data.frame / data.table` inputs so far.

`rbind` for data.tables now coerces non-data.table list elements to data.tables first and then calls `rbindlist` internally. [This commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/0b033b24a4a84e55723efab9a1664dc3c4151fae) fixes the issue and should be available from v1.9.8 on. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md):

> 71. `rbind` for data.tables now coerces non-list inputs to data.tables first before calling `rbindlist` so that binding list of data.tables and matrices work as expected to be consistent with base's rbind, [#1626](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1626). Thanks @ems for reporting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34426957/559784) on SO.

---

This looks like a reproducible `data.table` bug. I've filed it [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1626). Thanks for posting it!

```
require(psych)
require(data.table)
> DT = data.table(a=1:5,b=6:10)
> alpha(DT)
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Item 2 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
> setDF(DT)
> alpha(DT)  # works

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 15.10

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.7 psych_1.5.8     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] parallel_3.2.2 mnormt_1.5-4  
>
```